# Wireless logitech keyboard to wired

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, laptop-repair, repair, wireless-keyboard

i have a Logitech K850 keyboard i use it to play, before it didnt have input lag but now it has, i thinks is because the interference of 2.4ghz,can i convert the keyboard to a USB one to avoid input lag?, some ideas of how can i do it?, i have the receiver, and i was wondering if i can do something like remove the antennas from the receiver also for the keyboard and solder cables between them directly, but idk if this would work, it uses the logitech unifying receiver

Comment: Never tried this on the Logitech, but Apple wireless keyboards can do this - simple test, plug the keyboard to USB, unplug the dongle. Does it still work, or is the cable only good for charging?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do and is demonstrated in the YouTube video
[Wireless Keyboard Into Wired keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qvd_3sGMd2o),
using a USB cable cannibalized from a USB mouse.

However, the risk to the keyboard is great, that it will never work again
after this operation.

It would be simpler to buy a new keyboard.

Comment: is only for power not data